# Selenium Web Scraping to proper Column

Tags: python, selenium, csv

Sorry for this dumb question, I promise I've been looking for an answer and trying different things now for about 4 days and I'm tried of banging my head against the wall. Basically I'm using Selenium to scrape information from a website and I'm saving that information piece by piece into a .csv file. I want to know HOW can I save that information to the proper column using an object So that its changeable.

```
    def grab_id(self, xUrl, xID, xColumn):
        self.id = xID
        self.url = xUrl
        self.column = xColumn
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(self.url)
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        find_id = driver.find_element_by_id(self.id)
        xTitle = driver.title
        f = open('Jasoom.csv', 'a')
        f.write(str(xTitle) + '\n')



        time.sleep(5)
        for id in find_id:
            f.write(str(id.text) + '\n') <---- how can I tell to Column 5 in the main function?
        driver.quit()
        f.close()
```

gh.grab_id('www.tesla.com', 'Peanut-butter', Column_5) <--Just wont work no matter what I try??

if you guys know that would be so awesome. Thank you for taking the time to even read this, have a happy holidays and thanks for any feedback!!

Comment: This does not answer your Column 5 question, however, I can see an issue with your code. find_element_by_id returns a WebElement object and not an iterable. You can use find_elements_by_id and then iterate over the results.

Comment: Thank you for you anwser! But right now it has no problem finding the id because I am using the for loop to gather up all the id's but once I save them to a csv its a jumbled mess and I hate cleaning the data by hand lol

Comment: You want to add the text to column 5 of the next row in your csv file? or column 5 of any row?

Comment: I've never tried writing to a CSV in this way. I've generally done it by writing top to bottom, left to right without any skipping around. Having said that, you can probably create your own data structure like a two dimensional string array so that you can write to any row or column. Once you've finished scraping and have your string array loaded, just write that to a CSV.

Comment: Great question! I was hoping to create a list that just keeps adding and doesn't change the previous information before it. So for example, I was hoping it just keeps adding to Column 5 without changing whatever row that may be.

Comment: If you want to change text in column 5 in whatever row and your output file is not going to be very large (e.g. not more than 1 million rows), you can save the outout file in .xlsx format and use openxl library. With openxl, you can access and edit specific cells (e.g. sheet[row][column]).